# How to find IP addresses of devices on local network which are running an instance of my app in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, sockets

I'm working on a simple Swift app where one user can find other machines on a local network which are running an instance of my app and then send data to that machine using TCP sockets.

My question is **how to find IP addresses of devices on same network which are running an instance of my app (cross-platform)?**

- I was thinking about listing all devices on local network and then
  checking whether they have opened specific port (the port my app is
  using)?
- I also found that Apple provides service called Bonjour which could make my process discoverable. I'm not sure if this solution is good for cross-platform communication.

Answer (score 0):

Apart of Mac-related stuff and high-level solutions (I believe keywords "network service discovery" will bring you to them), there are a couple of things that will work for a local network:

**I** Have a server that clients should report to. Some short hello-like UDP message and a timeout mechanism will be sufficient to keep a list of available clients in the network.

**II** Use IP or UDP *multicast groups* to notify others that a client has just connected to the network. Send a message to a multicast group and listen to this group to build a list of clients.

However, broadcasts and multicasts won't be transmitted through a router. So if your network is large enough only neighbouring clients will hear your notification. In order to overcome it,

**III** DHCP servers can be configured to provide custom data to clients via [unassigned DHCP options](https://www.mattfischer.com/blog/?p=132). Large networks have usually such server. You probably can use it to send out a list of clients, but I'm not sure about this.